# Android Wear Version number in 4 places

Tags: android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, wear-os

Every time I upgrade my Android Wear App version number I have to change 2 lines in 4 files to the exact same value
For clarity I am refering to `versionCode` and `versionName` in

1. mobile/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml
2. wear/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml
3. mobile/build.gradle
4. wear/build.gradle

It just doesn't feel right

Is there a standard way to centralize the version numbers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I went through the same pain and have come up with the following;

Firstly you don't need to include the version details within your manifest files if they are in the build.gradle.

To centralise the version numbers in the two build.gradle files add your version details into the gradle.properties at the root project level, creating the file if it's missing:

```
# Project-wide Gradle settings: gradle.properties
VERSION_NAME=2.2.1
VERSION_CODE=207
```

Then in your build.gradle files within your wear and mobile apps change the versions to reference the project variables

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
    ...
    versionName project.VERSION_NAME
    versionCode Integer.parseInt(project.VERSION_CODE)
    }
}
```

That way you only have to change your project level gradle.properties when you want to update the version details.

Comment: @Shine you can create one in your root project folder, just add what I've detailed in my post.